# Why does a nil nib name not work?

Tags: ios, nib

Usually when I pass in `nil` as the first parameter of `initWithNibName:bundle:` it will automatically find the name, but sometimes it doesn't and it just shows a black screen.  Under what circumstances does this happen?  There are no errors in the console window and the app happily keeps running as a black screen unless I change the `nil` to a string literal of the nib name.  Where can I check to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never passed "`nil`" in the first parameter of [`[UIViewController initWithNibName: bundle:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) before, but Apple's documentation says:

> If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override
>   the loadView method, the view controller searches for a nib file using
>   other means. See nibName.

So presumably you're doing something in your loadView method.

It's probably safest (and a best practice) to probably just specify the explicit .xib name when instantiating your view controller.

Comment: The thing I like about nil, though, is that if I refactor the class name it will change automatically.  Interesting about the loadView section though!  That was exactly it.  Nice find.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely have a viewcontroller to nib name inconsistancy
The role of loading nib are like following

If you pass nil to the nib name the sdk will do the following

> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController,
>      it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName)

Comment: this information comes from [Apple's documentation for the UIViewController nibName property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName)

Comment: yes @MichaelDautermann am sorry i forgot to include it, ill edit the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use init instead and override viewDidLoad.